# Django migration not applying changes despite announcing otherwise

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to remove a column from a table in Django.

I removed the field from the `models.py` file as well as any reference to it elsewhere.

I ran `docker-compose exec api python manage.py migrate` and `docker-compose exec api python manage.py makemigrations my_db` where I was informed that:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying my_classes.0002_remove_myclass_column_to_remove... OK
```

But when I manually explore the database `my_db`, the column is still present.

The contents of the latest migration file:

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.7 on 2019-06-06 12:57

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myclass', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='myclass',
            name='column_to_remove',
        ),
    ]
```

Why hasn't my migration taken effect properly?

Comment: You sure you are looking at the correct database, and it is refreshed in your database client?

Comment: I only have one database, how would  Icheck if it is refreshed?

Comment: It depends on the database client, but in general, you might need to update the schema to see the updated version of db schema